# MD5 checksum on multiple file?

Tags: macos

I have files like this.

```
md1.gz
md1.gz.md5
md2.gz
md2.gz.md5
....
md300.gz
md300.gz.md
```

Is there any application (or command line) to check the md5 of all files ?

EDIT: Currently I use cfv from macport. work great without any modification

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `md5` command will check multiple files for you. Simply list all the files you want after the command. I.e. `md5 md1.gz md2.gz md3.gz`. It will output the md5 hashes like so:

```
MD5 (md1.gz) = 1c2c02b085a1bc2fed683eca86c0df02
MD5 (md1.gz) = c5515451d8f90a822457a4a8e4bf1791
```

If you want just the hashes, use the `-q` flag, it will print only the hash, without the identifying information.

I'm guessing that you want to compare the hash of the files against that in the corresponding .md5 file. You could write a quick shell script to check each generated hash against the one stored in the .md5 file.

Something like this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "$@"; do
  generatedhash=$(md5 -q "$file")
  storedhash=$(< "$file".md5)
  if [[ $generatedhash != $storedhash ]]; then
    echo "Hash for file '$file 'does not match"
  fi
done
```

Save that to a text file, call it something like checkmd5.sh and do `chmod +x checkmd5.sh` in the terminal.

It will print out a warning for all files that don't have a matching hash. It prints nothing if the hashes do match. It's quick and dirty, so apologies if it doesn't work for your particular case. But based on the examples you gave, if you run `./checkmd5.sh md*.gz` it should check the hashes of the .gz files against the corresponding .md5 files and tell you if any are bad.

Comment: I remember using "something" in linux box to do a hash check with multiple file but I can't remember so I wonder if osx have the same thing.

Comment: Glad it's what you're looking for. I added a sample script that should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

md5deep is a great cross platform tool to generate and check md5/sha hashes.
While it's easy to replicate the recursive hash generation feature in a few lines of shell code, it's not so easy to do that for its hash matching feature.

http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/start-md5deep.html#install

Answer (score -1):

If want to use a gui, you can try with [ff_md5drop](http://www.fftools.eu/projects/ff_md5drop/ff_md5drop.html)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe my own product will help you.
fHash https://github.com/sunjw/fhash
An open source files' hash calculator for Windows and Mac OS X.

- MD5, SHA1, SHA256 and CRC32.
- Drag & drop.
- Integrated with context menu in Explorer/Finder.
- Support multiple files.

Comment: Please read the Help section on self-promotion & disclosure - http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/promotion

Comment: @Tetsujin I think this is an answer of the question, why it is "-3"? I just came across this question, and I think fHash which is my own product is useful for this situation. And answers above mine are all just a tool's link. So why you don't flag them?

Comment: Did you read my link? You need to disclose any affiliation to product.

Comment: In general, answers which show *how* a specific product can be used to solve the specific problem described in the question tend to get better votes than answers which just link to a product together with a generic text. This is especially valid if you promote your own product.